# Does Spark dataset.write() result in the rows being collected at the driver node?

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to fine tune the performance a spark job that writes the results of a processed data set (on cluster) to the HDFS and also to a relational database. I am using dataset.write().jdbc() and dataset.write().csv() methods respectively. I am wondering if these methods will result in all the rows being collected to the driver node, thus impacting the performance of the job ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Each executor writes its own RDD unless you use `collect` or `coalesce` in your code.

Comment: Oh I did use coalesce ! Do I really need to ? I just copied some existing code blindly !

Comment: If you have multiple executors, each executor will write its own file but as an example, if you want a single file. Then you use coalesce(1). This call gets all the data to driver and then writes a single file. If you are fine with multiple files, you don't need that.

Comment: By multiple files you mean different part files of the same file ? Apparently I give one file name and path to the csv() method and want to be able to read that file back with that name . Also what effect does coalesce have on write.jdbc given that all the rows go to the same table anyways in the database.

Comment: Yes by multiple files I meant multiple part files. If you just want to write rows to a database, you can easily remove coalesce.
We had a client requirement to write a single parquet file but we got that removed due to performance issue. So unless you have a very specific requirement, it is not required.

Answer (score 3):

> Does Spark dataset.write() result in the rows being collected at the driver node?

It does not. All `DataFrameWriter` methods work directly (each executor writes its own part of the data) without collecting.